# JOOQ: generating update SQL for table named by String

Tags: java, jooq, sql-generation

I just want to use JOOQ to generate SQL without it validating tables, columns, etc., and without it generating classes for said tables, columns, etc.

How can I generate a SQL update, and just specify the name of the schema & table with `String`s?

Maybe later I'll setup the table-generated Java code, but it's not necessary right now.  If I can't use JOOQ without such generated code, then I'll use some other library for now.

Thanks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/27083958/521799

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use source code generation to use jOOQ's DSL API. See, for instance:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-standalone-sql-builder
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/names

In your case, given you want to generate a SQL update, how about:

```java
// Assuming this static import
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

using(configuration)
   .update(table("my_table"))
   .set(field("id", Integer.class), 1)
   .set(field("value", String.class), "A")
   .where("x > ?", 3)
   .execute();
```